# PySpark DataFrame: Longformat to wide format

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of customers who bought Items:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('A','Item1'), ('A','Item3'), ('B','Item1'), ('B','Item2')])
df=rdd.toDF(['Person','Item'])
df.show()
+------+-----+
|Person| Item|
+------+-----+
|     A|Item1|
|     A|Item3|
|     B|Item1|
|     B|Item2|
+------+-----+
```

Now I would like to change this to wide format using pyspark. The result should look like this:

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+
|Person|Item1|Item2|Item3|
+------+-----+-----+-----+
|     A|  1  |  0  |  0  |
|     A|  0  |  0  |  1  |
|     B|  1  |  0  |  0  |
|     B|  0  |  1  |  0  |
+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Any idea how to do this?

Best regards,
Felix

Answer (score -1):

I actually found the solution:

```
>>> df.crosstab('Person', 'Item').show()
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+
|Person_Item|Item1|Item2|Item3|
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+
|          A|    1|    0|    1|
|          B|    1|    1|    0|
+-----------+-----+-----+-----+
```